# How to get thumbnail of a file?

Tags: thumbnails

I have a `xcf` file which is corrupted and can't be recovered but it still has thumbnail which is large enough for me. I checked `~/.thumbnails` to get it to my home folder but there are 9900 files (I guess they are named with md5) and I can't check them all.

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. How can I get the corresponding `thumbnail.png` of a file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any easy way to do this. (I assume you don't have a backup from which you can restore the `xcf` file?)

You could try searching the thumbnail directory for files created after the timestamp of your `xcf` to see if that reduces the number of thumbnail images you need to review:

```
mkdir newer_thumbs
find .thumbnails -type f -newer 'corrupted.xcf' -exec ln --target newer_thumbs {} +
```

This will create a `newer_thumbs` directory containing only thumbnails that were created more recently that your `corrupted.xcf` file. (You can delete the entire folder when you're done, as it contains only links to the full set of thumbnails.)

Answer (score -2):

```
XFCE Menu --> Settings --> Keyboard >>> Application Shortcuts,
```

Add the `xfce4-screenshooter -f` command to use the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key in order to take fullscreen screenshots.

Check Arch Linux wiki for more details. Or look at http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/start